# Using adb in bash is giving different results than expected

Tags: android, bash, adb

I have a bash script for uninstalling some software that is loaded onto our devices.

```
#!/bin/bash
APKS=`adb shell pm list packages projects`

for apk in $APKS
do
    apk=${apk##package:}
    echo "Uninstalling: $apk"
    adb uninstall $apk
done
```

When i run this script, all of the commands to uninstall an apk fail. However, when i run the exact same command (`adb uninstall projects.abd.def`) outside of the bash script, it executes successfully.

What am i doing wrong in the bash script?

Comment: possible duplicate of [adb uninstall command doesn't work in Bash shell for statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426070/adb-uninstall-command-doesnt-work-in-bash-shell-for-statement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue. I assumed there was a carriage return in the variable and had tested for this and it was still not working.

However, after googling a little more, i realized i was chopping off the carriage return incorrectly.

Here is the correct way:

```
apk=`echo -n ${apk} | tr -d "\r"`
```