# List and remove developer installed android wear packages from windows?

Tags: android, adb, wear-os, watchface

I have a couple watchfaces that were installed while working on a watch face in android studio.

I'm using Android Studio with windows and a USB connection to the watch. How can I remove the packages? I tried adb with no luck, receiving the error "delete failed internal error."

I might not be entering the correct name of the package. Is there a way that I can list and remove the packages?

Edit, thanks to String the problem has been solved. Here's how.

```
adb -d shell pm list packages
```

This lists the packages installed on the device. The "-d" flag directs the command to the usb device.

If my app is named my.app, the listing will show as package:my.app
The following will delete that package.

```
adb -d shell pm uninstall my.app
```

d.datul1990 recommend stackoverflow.com/questions/13534935/adb-uninstall-failed which shows that adb can open up a shell.

```
adb -d root
adb -d shell
```

will open up a linux like shell where "pm list packages" and "pm uninstall some.package" can be entered along with ls and cd to list and change directories and such.

On my windows 10 installation adb.exe was in C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\
To run adb from windows, open up a command window in its directory. This option may be found by holding down the sift key while 'right' clicking inside the folder in explorer to get the option "Open command window here".

Comment: Have you tried reading this: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13534935/adb-uninstall-failed this ticket solve the issue `delete failed internal error` adb

Comment: @d.datul1990 I had seen that post, but I thought it was for linux. I had not realized that adb shell provides a linux like environment. If I had known that when I first read it, it might have helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to have the correct package name to uninstall. You can list all installed packages with

```
adb shell pm list packages
```